# echo json_encode is conflicting with print_r and echo in php

Tags: php, json, ajax, echo

The below php is working well. Yet when you add a `print_r` or `echo` to the php to view any variable it sends the following error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after
>   JSON data at line 1 column 83 of the JSON data

.

```
        foreach ($ChangingMap as $key => $value){    

            $SqlVariables[$key]=array(
                'id' => $ChangingMap[$key]['element_id'],
                'action' => $ChangingMap[$key]['e_action'],
                'record' => $ChangingMap[$key]['e_record'],
                'table' => $ChangingMap[$key]['e_table'],
                'ascendant' => $ChangingMap[$key]['ascendant'],
                'where' => $ChangingMap[$key]['descendant']   
            );          
            if ($ChangingMap[$key]['status']==$Basic_Status[0]){  
                for($i=0;$i<sizeof($Variable_holder);$i++){
                    $carrier=explode("|", $ChangingMap[$key][$Variable_holder[$i]]);
                    $SqlVariables[$key][$Query_Variable_holder[$i]]=$carrier[0];
                }
                $SqlVariables[$key]['where']=$Query_Destination[0];
            }

            $SqlQuery[$key]= $SqlVariables[$key]['action'].' '.$SqlVariables[$key]['record'].' FROM '.$SqlVariables[$key]['table'].' WHERE ' .$SqlVariables[$key]['where'].'="'.$ChangingArr[1].'"';                
            $SqlArray[]=array(
                'id' => $ChangingMap[$key]['element_id'], 
                'sql'=>  $SqlQuery[$key]
            );
            $ClearStr='';
            $test=CallData('Changing',$SqlArray[$key]['id'],$SqlArray[$key]['sql'],$ClearStr);
        }

    }
    //print_r($test);
    echo json_encode($test);
}
```

The javascript function is as follows

```
function Administrator(){
    $(document).on('change',function(e){
        if(e.target.tagName ==="SELECT"){        
            ChangingSelect="Changing|"+e.target.id+"|"+$( '#' +e.target.id + ' option:selected' ).text();
            //console.log(ChangingSelect);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",        
                url: "ChangingTool.php?ChangingSelect="+ChangingSelect})
            .done(function(data){    
                    var Mydata = JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log("hi");
                    $.each(Mydata, function (i,item) {
                        var SelectedDataArr=Mydata[i].selected.split('|').filter(function(x){return (x !== (undefined || null || ""));});
                        $('#'+Mydata[i].id).empty();
                        $.each(SelectedDataArr,function(j,item){

                            $('#'+Mydata[i].id).append('<option value="' + j + '">'+ SelectedDataArr[j]+'</option>');
                        });
                    });

            });
        }
    });
}
```

How to overcome this issue? It is restricting my ability to test my variables.

Comment: We don't see the whole PHP (thank you), I'd guess there is some characters left by some other echo's throughout the PHP scripts... Could you double check with your developer tools that the body of the response is strictly just the JSON object?

Comment: Make sure you are getting a valid JSON string from PHP response.

Comment: If you just want to debug the JSON response (`print_r($test)`) I suggest using your browser developer tools (`F12` shortcut usually) to inspect the response, there you have a nice JSOn viewer and everything you need.

Comment: *Log* debug output into a file. As a bad hack, perhaps output them into HTTP *headers*. But, yes, if you output anything in the body that isn't JSON then your JSON isn't valid JSON. The only answer here is: *simply don't do it.*

Comment: I'm getting the error on the browser developer tool. the code is working perfectly. The code is working well, if i add a [ print_r("hi") ] it will show the error.

Comment: If you only have one `echo json_encode(...)` in your code and you still get a parse error you might have some other output from PHP (maybe a warning or some other thing). Can you edit your question and copy the whole response from the request in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply don't output debug messages into your data. Of course that will break your data. Use [`error_log`](http://php.net/error_log), [`syslog`](http://php.net/syslog), or something like a plain `file_put_contents('debug.log', var_export($foo, true), FILE_APPEND)` to output debug data to a log file instead.